# How to serve another static root in Django for html pages?

Tags: django, python-sphinx

The typical configuration serves two static roots:

```
http://www.example.org/static/
http://www.example.org/media/
```

This is `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL`.

I would like to add a third one to host static files build with Sphinx:

```
http://www.example.org/docs/
```

I know I could configure this on the level of the web server. Is it also possible to configure this on the level of Django?

Here is my python package, that implements Sphinx with Django templates and renders it to static pages. A kind lightweight read-the-docs. Still in an early state, yet working.

https://github.com/elmar-hinz/Django.SphinxCMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about building a url just like you do for the static files? The `DOCS_ROOT` setting should be a string in your settings.

```
from django.urls import re_path    
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^docs/(?P<path>.*)', serve, {'document_root': settings.DOCS_ROOT})
]
```

Comment: Thanks, great! It's working out of the box. I edited your answer to also serve in development mode.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you!

Comment: Sorry, my edit was rejected by two of three, with the remark I should put that into a comment. I can't put code into a comment.